# Can we check the color of button in controller action in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have multiple text boxes on one view. At the time of post method i want that if the button color has been changed only then the values should be inserted for that particular records, Other values should not be inserted.

In this case if i am fire onclick event than the color of textbox is changing. I just want to know that can i get the color of button in the action controller.

According to that i can fire insert operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the color of the button that's important to the controller, it's what that color represents. So post whatever *that* to the controller and deal with it accordingly. If you're dealing with presentation issues like "color" inside your controller, you're missing the point of MVC.